# Strange behaviour where initialised map being reported as empty

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2019, stdmap

I have the three following files:

test.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Test{
public:
    Test(std::string string);
};
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include <map>

std::map<int, int> HEY = {
    {1, 45},
    {2, 2}
};


Test::Test(std::string string)  {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    if (HEY.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Is empty!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not empty!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include "test.h"

Test test("hey");


int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output

```
hello
Not empty!
```

Actual Output

```
hello
Is empty!
```

When I run the program in Microsoft Visual Studio 2019, I expect "Not empty!" to be outputted, indicating that the map `HEY` has elements within it, since it's initialised with two pairs. However the output is actually "Is empty!".

I do not want to initialise `test` within the main function, because I want it to be a global variable, although I notice that when I do create it in the main function I get the correct output.

What am I doing wrong? Is this a compiler/linker error? Am I not declaring the `HEY` map appropriately? It is essential that `test` remains a global variable.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof

Comment: This is called *static initialization order fiasco*.  There are many post here on SO that show different ways to deal with it.  Which one I leave to you to decide to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `HEY` and `test` objects are both being created in global memory at program startup before `main()` is called.  The `test` object is simply being created first, that is why the `map` is still empty when `test`'s constructor is run (technically, the `map` hasn't even been created yet).  See [Static Initialization Order Fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).

Move the creation of the `test` object into `main()` and you should see the output you are expecting.  Otherwise, you will have to delay the initialization of `HEY` until after `test`, such as by wrapping `HEY` inside a singleton that initializes it the first time it is used, eg:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <map>

struct MapSingleton {
    static std::map<int, int>& Get() {
        static std::map<int, int> HEY = {
            {1, 45},
            {2, 2}
        };
        return HEY;
    }
};

Test::Test(std::string string)  {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    if (MapSingleton::Get().empty()) {
        std::cout << "Is empty!" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Not empty!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the information and example! Really helped a lot!

Comment: What would the naming convention be for these Singleton objects? And would one singleton house multiple Get() functions, or is it preferred to keep them in individual Singleton objects?

Comment: @Tom use whatever naming convention you want that is meaningful to you.  Names don't exist in the final compiled executable. Whether you use 1 singleton or multiple, that is entirely up to you.